# Does Taraweeh replace Tahajjud prayer in the Month of Ramadan?

Tags: salat, ramadan, taraweeh, tahajjud

As per my reading I do not find any occurance of the word "Tarawih" in hadith literature , was such a word known at the time of Prophet pbuh or is it that Taraweeh is just a special name given to the Tahajjud Prayer in Ramdan.

Comment: According to this [yahoo answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110416202637AATp4CB), they are the same except that you can still offer tahajjad after taraweeh. The conditions are a little bit different for the two. For Tahajjud you are suppose to sleep first then offer prayer, for taraweeh it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tarwiha*, the singular of *Tarawih*, refers to the period of rest between every four rakat of the prayer.  *Salat at-Tarawih* was so-named because of these rests, which differentiated it from the normal *Salat at-Tahajjud*.

As far as I know, *Salat at-Tarawih* is the same as *Salat at-Tahajjud*, only performed earlier and with frequent rests to make it easier on the people during Ramadan.